# Replace a word in a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, file

I am new to Ruby and I have been trying to replace a word in a file. The code for that is as follows:

```
File.open("hello.txt").each do |li|
  if (li["install"])
  li ["install"] = "latest"
  puts "the goal state set to install, changed to latest"
  end
end
```

While the message in puts gets printed once, the word does not change to "latest" in that line of that file. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll also need to write back to the file. `File.open` without any arguments opens the file for reading. You can try this:

```
# load the file as a string
data = File.read("hello.txt") 
# globally substitute "install" for "latest"
filtered_data = data.gsub("install", "latest") 
# open the file for writing
File.open("hello.txt", "w") do |f|
  f.write(filtered_data)
end
```

Comment: f.puts would be more concise!

Comment: @Drew Not the same though, that always adds a newline, so you'll have an empty last line in the document. Also not much shorter. You can use `f << filtered_data`, though.

Answer (score 12):

Or you can make it a one liner

```
File.write("hello.txt",File.open("hello.txt",&:read).gsub("install","latest"))
```

Comment: Technically that's 2 lines, but +1 for slick `File.open(filename, &:read)`, never really thought about that one.

Comment: yes well obviously you could put the filename in the method. Edited to prove my point :) thanks for the +1

Comment: Is `File.open("hello.txt",&:read)` better in some way than just `File.read('hello.txt')`? Didn't know you could use that `to_proc` like that though, thanks for that.

Comment: @KeithBennett nope there is no particular functional difference I just like the way it looks and a method using `File::read` was already presented at the time of posting

Comment: more concise: `IO.write("hello.txt", IO.read("hello.txt").gsub("install", "latest"))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you're not writing the changed line to the file.

I would recommend this:

```
lines = IO.readlines("hello.txt")
for line in lines
    if line["install"]
        line["install"] = "latest"
    end
end
f = File.open("hello.txt", "w")
for line in lines
    f.puts(line)
end
f.close
```

In line 1, `IO.readlines()` returns an array containing all the lines in the file. The rest of the program is fundamentally the same until we get to line 6, where the file is opened. File mode "w" tells Ruby to overwrite the file, which is what we want here. In line 8, we use file.puts to write each of the lines back to the file, with modifications. We use `puts` instead of `write` because and all the newlines were clipped off by `IO.readlines()`, and `puts` appends newlines while `write` does not. Finally, line 10 closes the file.